# MVC Kendogrid checkbox values not saving in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

The grid is editable and the checkbox checks fine.  But when submitting the grid its saving to the db as unchecked (except for last row).  Any ideas why?

Here is my grid html:

```
<div class="k-widget k-grid col-md-11" id="ParticipantList" data-role="grid" style="overflow: visible;">
```

Participant ID

IDT Participant Name

In Person
 


0
 
 



0
 
 


0

Another grid on same page, both experienceing same issue:

```
<div class="k-widget k-grid col-md-11" id="FamilyMemberList" data-role="grid" style="overflow: visible;">
<table role="grid" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="FamilyMemberList_active_cell">
<colgroup>
<col style="width:30%">
<col style="width:30%">
<col style="width:15%"><
col style="width:15%">
<col></colgroup>
<thead class="k-grid-header"><tr>
<th class="k-header" data-field="ParticipantID" data-title="Participant ID" scope="col" style="display:none" data-role="sortable"><a class="k-link" tabindex="-1">Participant ID</a>
</th><th class="k-header" data-field="ParticipantName" data-title="Name of person Invited" scope="col" data-role="sortable">
<a class="k-link"  tabindex="-1">Name of person Invited</a></th>
<th class="k-header" data-field="Relationship" data-title="Relationship" scope="col" data-role="sortable" id="FamilyMemberList_active_cell"><a class="k-link" tabindex="-1">Relationship</a></th>
<th class="k-header" data-field="HasAttended" data-title="Attended" scope="col" data-role="sortable">
<a class="k-link" tabindex="-1">Attended</a></th>
<th class="k-header" data-field="IsInPerson" data-title="In Person" scope="col" data-role="sortable">
<a class="k-link" tabindex="-1">In Person</a></th>
<th class="k-header" scope="col"><span class="k-link">&nbsp;</span></th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr data-uid="b09ff8d6-04ab-4ff6-8db2-71cc10887fd4" role="row">
<td style="display:none" role="gridcell">0<input type="hidden" name="FamilyMemberList[0].ParticipantID" value="0"></td>
<td role="gridcell"><span> </span><input type="hidden" name="FamilyMemberList[0].ParticipantName" class="participantName0" value=""></td>
<td role="gridcell"><span> </span><input type="hidden" name="FamilyMemberList[0].Relationship" class="relationShip0" value=""></td>
<td role="gridcell"><input type="checkbox" class="HasAttendedChkBx"><input type="hidden" name="FamilyMemberList[0].HasAttended"></td>
<td role="gridcell"><input type="checkbox" class="InPersonChkBx"><input type="hidden" name="FamilyMemberList[0].IsInPerson"></td>
<td role="gridcell"><a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-deletethisrow" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="k-alt" data-uid="6689f6db-9bda-41c0-9932-655522267838" role="row"><td style="display:none" role="gridcell">0<input type="hidden" name="FamilyMemberList[1].ParticipantID" value="0"></td>
<td role="gridcell"><span> </span><input type="hidden" name="FamilyMemberList[1].ParticipantName" class="participantName1" value=""></td>
<td role="gridcell"><span> </span><input type="hidden" name="FamilyMemberList[1].Relationship" class="relationShip1" value=""></td>
<td role="gridcell"><input type="checkbox" class="HasAttendedChkBx"><input type="hidden" name="FamilyMemberList[1].HasAttended"></td>
<td role="gridcell"><input type="checkbox" class="InPersonChkBx"><input type="hidden" name="FamilyMemberList[1].IsInPerson"></td>
<td role="gridcell"><a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-deletethisrow" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td></tr>
<tr data-uid="f7610caf-3cc5-4592-8f13-b3a0a933179f" role="row" class="">
<td style="display:none" role="gridcell" class="" data-role="editable">0<input type="hidden" name="FamilyMemberList[2].ParticipantID" value="0"></td>
<td role="gridcell"><span> </span><input type="hidden" name="FamilyMemberList[2].ParticipantName" class="participantName2" value=""></td>
<td role="gridcell"><span> </span><input type="hidden" name="FamilyMemberList[2].Relationship" class="relationShip2" value=""></td>
<td role="gridcell"><input type="checkbox" class="HasAttendedChkBx"><input type="hidden" name="FamilyMemberList[2].HasAttended"></td>
<td role="gridcell"><input type="checkbox" class="InPersonChkBx"><input type="hidden" name="FamilyMemberList[2].IsInPerson"></td>
<td role="gridcell"><a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-deletethisrow" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

jquery:

```
$('#FamilyMemberList').on('click', '.HasAttendedChkBx', function () {
        var hasAttendedHiddenInput = $(this).siblings("input[type='hidden']");
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            hasAttendedHiddenInput.val("true");
            console.log('FamilyMemberList - hasAttended' + hasAttendedHiddenInput.val());
        } else {
            hasAttendedHiddenInput.val("");
            console.log('FamilyMemberList - hasAttended' + hasAttendedHiddenInput.val());
        }
    });

    $('#CareConferenceParticipantList').on('click', '.IsInPersonChkBx', function (e) {
        var isInPersonHiddenInput = $(this).siblings("input[type='hidden']");
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            isInPersonHiddenInput.val("true");
            console.log('FamilyMemberList - inPerson' + isInPersonHiddenInput.val());
        } else {
            isInPersonHiddenInput.val("");
            console.log('FamilyMemberList - inPerson' + isInPersonHiddenInput.val());
        }
    });
```

Any help would be most appreciative, thanks

Comment: What is the actual html your code is generating for the checkboxes?

Comment: @StephenMuecke have you seen my code

Comment: If your binding to a `bool` property, then you cannot set the value to `null` - it needs to be `hasAttendedHiddenInput.val("false");` (not `.val("")`. And the hidden inputs for the `bool` properties should include a `value` attribute ("True" or "False") based on the initial value of the property